# How to ensure an array has even number of elements

Tags: c++

So i have used a rand() to generate a random string of digits in an array. However, i only want an even number of digits to be generated. Example: 675986 (6 digits generated) or 56237946 (8 digits generated).

This is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 30;


void constructArray(char[], int);

void printArray (const char[], int);


int main()
{
    char str [MAX];
    int n;

    srand(time(NULL));

    n = rand() % 20 + 4;

    constructArray(str, n);
    printArray(str, n);

}

void constructArray(char str[], int n)
{
    char digits [] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};

    int k;




    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        k = rand() % 10;
        str [i] = digits[k];



        if (str[0] == '0')
        {
            str[0] = digits[k] + 1;
        }

    }

}

void printArray (const char str [], int n)
{
    cout << "Given ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << str [i];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `char ch = '0' + 2 * (rand() % 5)`?

Answer (score 1):

In `main()` you determine the number `n` of digits:

```
n = rand() % 20 + 4;
```

To check if it's even, just do `!(n&1)`. You can then or decrement it if it's odd. Alternatively you can also go directly to `(~1&n)` which just convert your number to an even number.   [Online demo](http://ideone.com/TYmDMG)

***Additional explanations:***

This works using [bit manipulation magics](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).  It checks if the least significant bit is set, which is true if and only if the number is odd. The alternative resets the least significant bit, ensuring that the number is even.  It transforms positive odd number in the nearest smaller even number, so that it will remain under your current upper bound of 24.

Comment: `rand() % 10 * 2 + 4`?

Comment: @MooingDuck :-) Yes that's even simpler ! But OP can keep my answer in case he has numbers on which he has less control (e.g. `cin>>n;`)  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use integer division to your benefit:

```
n = rand() % 20 + 4;
n = n / 2;
n = n * 2;
```

or you could just check if it's odd:

`if (n % 2 != 0) n = n + 1;`

Comment: I don't know if it's of interest but the original number is between 4 and 23. With 23 you would increment beyond these boundaries, which could be an issue if MAX appeared to be defined as 24.